# Sorting by Subtraction

Tags: java, sorting

So I was working on this sorting algorithm in java, and was wondering if anybody has seen anything like this before. Specifically, this algorithm is meant to sort very large lists with a very small range of numbers. If you have seen that or have any suggestions to enhance the algorithm, can you say something about that below? I have the code here:

```
public static int[] sort(int[] nums)
{   
    int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for (int n : nums)
    {
        if (n < lowest)
            lowest = n;
    }

    int index = 0;

    int down = 0;

    while (index < nums.length)
    {
        for (int i = index; i < nums.length; i++)
        {
            if (nums[i] == lowest)
            {
                int temp = nums[i] + down;
                nums[i] = nums[index];
                nums[index] = temp;

                index++;
            }
            else 
                nums[i]--;
        }
        down++;
    }

    return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, that is your standard-issue BubbleSort. It's simple to implement but has poor performance: O(n^2). Notice the two nested loops: as the size of the array increases, the runtime of the algorithm will increase exponentially.

It's named Bubble Sort because the smallest values will "bubble" to the front of the array, one at a time. You can read more about it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: The way I thought it went is that it doesn't run in n^2 time, but instead in range*length time (the times it goes through doesn't rely solely on the length), so that it is decently efficient if you are sorting a long list with a small range. Run it yourself under these conditions, let me know if there's a difference at all (I have some conditions I used earlier in a response to a comment down below).

Comment: I bit of explanation on how it works; although I do have two nested loops, the     while(index < nums.length)    doesn't move linearly like you think. It essentially says "keep running the loop until everything is sorted," and index can move up several times in one iteration. The times that loop will run is the same as the range of the array.

Answer (score 0):

So the algorithm seems to work but it does a lot of unnecessary work in the process.

Basically you are throwing in the necessity to subtract from a number x times before you add x back and try and swap it where x is the difference between the number and the lowest number in the array. Take [99, 1] for example. With your algorithm you would update the array to [98, 1] in the first for loop iteration and then the next you would make the swap [1, 98] then you have to make 97 more iterations to bring your down variable up to 98 and your array to [1,1] state then you add 98 to it and swap it with itself. Its an interesting technique for sure but its not very efficient.

The best algorithm for any given job really depends on what you know about your data. Look into other sorting algorithms to get a feel for what they do and why they do it. Make sure that you walk through the algorithm you make and try to get rid of unnecessary steps.

To enhance the algorithm first I would get rid of finding the lowest in the set and remove the addition and subtraction steps. If you know that your numbers will all be integers in a given range look into bucket sorting otherwise you can try merge or quicksort algorithms.

Comment: Yeah this algorithm is meant to be for specific purposes; it should only be used when the range is small, length is long. The more extremely the conditions are met, the better this algorithm is compared to those you listed.

Comment: I think that I'm right in this assertion, though if I'm not feel free to correct me.

Comment: Fair enough and in that scenario its not a bad method. It could be that a modified bucket sort would also be a good option (using the smallest number as a key modifier so you would increment the bucket array like bucket[nums[i]-lowest]++. This would reduced the total loops and computations that you would need to do (you would only need to visit each index twice worst case) Then you could use your bucket to fill in the values of your num index in the correct order (if you need the actual array of numbers back in the end) which would be one additional loop through all elements

Comment: I'm not familiar with the bucket sort, but I think I got the idea of it from your comment. It is a decent bit more efficient and is pretty light on memory use. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries! Keep being creative and doing things in new ways and don't be afraid to not get a perfect solution. Creativity and working together to find better solutions is more important that knowing some random algorithm.