# Is there a sorting algorithm with linear time complexity and O(1) auxiliary space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, space-complexity

Is there a sorting algorithm with linear time complexity and `O(1)` auxiliary space complexity to sort a list of positive integers? I know that [radix sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radix-sort/) and [counting sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/) have linear time complexity (`O(kn)` and `O(n+k)` respectively if we take `k` as constant), but both of them have `O(n+k)` auxiliary space complexity. Is it even possible for a sort to have both of these properties? An example of such a sort would be appreciated.

Comment: This depends what you mean by "a sorting algorithm". Radix sort and counting sort assume more about the contents of the array than comparison-based sorting algorithms do, and are therefore applicable to fewer sorting problems. If you only want to sort a shuffled array containing the numbers from 1 to n, then you can do that in linear time and constant space, for example, but does this count as sorting?

Comment: Remember to bear in mind that what you're counting in "linear time complexity" - which is typically the number of comparisons _except_ for things like radix sort and counting sort - may not really be the right thing to count for your particular data.  E.g., for some data, comparisons might be (much) cheaper than copy/move/swap - and an in-place sort - which is what you're asking for with O(1) auxiliary space complexity - may end up costing you much more time due to need to copy/move/swap ... and I mean that not just in practice but also in theoretical complexity if only you counted it ...

Comment: @kaya3 I see your point. For now let us assume that the list only contains positive integers.

Comment: For comparison-based sorts, what you're asking for has been proven impossible.  I don't know where to find those proofs though.

Comment: @MarkRansom a simple proof is to consider that, to sort all possible inputs of length n (of which there are `n!`); comparison sorts that split that `n!` by half each time need at least `log2(n!)` steps to be correct (=sort all possible inputs correctly), which is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: And now for something completely different: sort any list in O(1) [Quantum Bogo Sort](http://wiki.c2.com/?QuantumBogoSort).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are sorting only integers, we can use the in-situ variant of counting sort which has `O(k)` space complexity, which is independent from the variable `n`. In other words when we treat `k` as constant, the space complexity is `O(1)`.

Alternatively, we can use [in place radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#In-place_MSD_radix_sort_implementations) with `lg k` phases of binary partition with `O(lg k)` space complexity (due to recursion). Or even less phases with the use of counting sort to determine the buckets boundaries for the n-way partition. These solutions sport time complexity of `O(lg k * n)`, which when expressed only in terms of the variable `n` is `O(n)` (when `k` is considered constant).

Another possible approach to obtain `O(n)` step complexity and `O(1)` space complexity, when `k` is considered constant, is to use something which can be called subtraction sort, as described by the OP in their [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63564345/821497), or [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501191/sorting-by-subtraction). It has step complexity `O(sum(input))` which is better than `O(kn)` (and for certain specific inputs it is even better than binary-radix sort's `O(lg k * n)`, e.g. for all inputs of the form `[k, 0, 0, ... 0]`) and space complexity `O(1)`.

Yet another solution is to use [bingo sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Variants) which has step complexity `O(vn)` where `v <= k` is the number of unique values in the input, and space complexity `O(1)`.

Note that neither of these sorting solutions are stable, which matters if we sort something more than just integers (some arbitrary objects with integer keys).

There is also a cutting edge stable partition algorithm described in this [paper](http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/%7Ejyrki/Paper/KP1992bJ.pdf) with `O(1)` space complexity. Combining it with radix sort, one may construct a stable linear sort algorithm with constant space - `O(lg k * n)` step complexity and `O(1)` space complexity.

---

### EDIT:

As per the request from the comment, I've tried to find a source for the "in-situ" variant of counting sort, but haven't found anything of good quality I could link to (it's really strange that there is no easily available description for such a basic algorithm). Therefore, I'm posting the algorithm here:

**The regular counting sort (from Wikipedia)**

```
count = array of k+1 zeros
for x in input do
    count[key(x)] += 1

total = 0
for i in 0, 1, ... k do
    count[i], total = total, count[i] + total

output = array of the same length as input
for x in input do
    output[count[key(x)]] = x
    count[key(x)] += 1 

return output
```

It assumes that the input consists of some objects which can be identified by an integer key in the range `0` to `k - 1`. It uses `O(n + k)` extra space.

**The trivial in-situ variant for integers**

This variant requires the input to be pure integers, not arbitrary objects with integer keys. It simply reconstructs the input array from the count array.

```
count = array of k zeros
for x in input do
    count[x] += 1

i = 0
for x in 0, 1, ... k - 1 do
    for j in 1, 2, ... count[x] do
        input[i], i = x, i + 1

return input
```

It uses `O(k)` extra space.

**The complete in-situ variant for arbitrary objects with integer keys**

This variant accepts arbitrary objects similarly to the regular variant. It uses swaps to place objects in appropriate places. After computing the `count` array in the two first loops it leaves it immutable, and uses another array called `done` to keep track of how many objects with a given key have been already placed in the right position.

```
count = array of k+1 zeros
for x in input do
    count[key(x)] += 1

total = 0
for i in 0, 1, ... k do
    count[i], total = total, count[i] + total

done = array of k zeros
for i in 0, 1, ... k - 1 do
    current = count[i] + done[i]
    while done[i] < count[i + 1] - count[i] do
        x = input[current]
        destination = count[key(x)] + done[key(x)]
        if destination = current then
            current += 1
        else
            swap(input[current], input[destination])
        done[key(x)] += 1 

return input
```

This variant is not stable, so it cannot be used as a subroutine in radix sort. It uses `O(2k) = O(k)` extra space.

Comment: "Consider `k` constant" is cheating. This way, you can make anything O(1). It's not clear what `k` actually is, but in my opinion OP made it very clear it's not a constant.

Comment: yup k is not a constant here and varies according to input. Therefore I would not consider this O(1) time.

Comment: @anatolyg Actually, the classic big-Oh notation is defined only for one variable (see https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/what-is-the-meaning-of-omn/3150#3150), and there's a whole discussion on what actually a multi-variable big-Oh means.

Comment: @Mathphile ok, I see. Then, probably the answer is that there is no such algorithm, but can't prove it now.

Comment: Also, notice that my answer gives some practical insights: e.g. we can sort 64-bit integers in linear time and constant space, because there is only a constant number of all possible 64-bit integers.

Comment: @ciamej could you add links/references to the in-situ varient of counting sort?

Comment: @Mathphile - w.r.t. in-situ wikipedia sez: "As described, counting sort is not an in-place algorithm; even disregarding the count array, it needs separate input and output arrays. It is possible to modify the algorithm so that it places the items into sorted order within the same array that was given to it as the input, using only the count array as auxiliary storage; however, the modified in-place version of counting sort is not stable.[3]" - but that isn't O(1) storage, merely in-situ - don't know if ciamej has a better result elsewhere

Comment: @Mathphile ok, I will add a reference (or I will place the algorithm here if I can't find a reputable source)

Comment: @ciamej could you check out the algorithm I made?

Comment: This answer is much more helpful now! +1 Could you let me know about your thoughts on my algorithm?

Comment: @Mathphile it seems that your algorithm has step complexity `O(kn)` and space complexity `O(1)`. While the binary-radix sort has step complexity `O(lg k * n)` and space complexity `O(1)`.

Comment: It means that your algorithm might work best only for very small `k`. In practice counting sort and binary-radix sort also work well only for small `k`. Otherwise, they are not that useful ;)

Comment: Yes I totally agree with you. Looks like at least someone understood my algorithm and agrees that the time complexity is O(kn). Now if only the people commenting under my answer would understand it too. Thanks for your help tho :)

Comment: @davidbak I've edited the answer to show the algorithm I was thinking about. I've never said that it has better space complexity than `O(k)`, just that `O(k)` equals `O(1)` when `k` is constant.

Comment: @ciamej maybe you could include my algorithm too in your answer if that's okay? I would like to accept your answer that gives a complete picture of all the methods found so far.

Comment: @Mathphile I can include your algorithm too, but I will just point to your answer. Also notice that you're definitely not the first to invent 'sorting by subtraction' ;) I have seen it multiple times. Fast google search gets me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501191/sorting-by-subtraction I'm not sure if that algorithm is different from yours or not, but the basic idea is the same.

Comment: I was already pretty sure that it existed. I just want to make all the methods more visible for people like me who have been searching for this.

Comment: @ciamej I got one more question. Is there a stable sort algorithm with linear time complexity, O(1) auxiliary space complexity to sort a list of positive integers?

Comment: @Mathphile assuming constant `k`, binary-radix sort can be considered such an algorithm.

Comment: @anatolyg Doesn't the OP make it clear that they *do* consider k constant? They call radix/counting sort "linear time", and that's only true if k is constant.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to include an algorithm here which is an improvement of Mathphile's first answer. In that case the idea was to shave `1` off of each number in the unsorted suffix of the input (while swapping sorted numbers into the prefix). Whenever a number in the unsorted suffix hits 0 it means it is smaller than any other number in the unsorted suffix (because all numbers are being reduced at the same rate).

There is a major improvement possible: with no change to time complexity we can subtract numbers much bigger than `1` - in fact we can subtract a number equal to the smallest remaining unsorted item. This allows this sort to function well regardless of the numeric sizes of the array items, and on floating point values! A javascript implementation:

```js
let subtractSort = arr => {
  
  let sortedLen = 0;
  let lastMin = 0; // Could also be `Math.min(...arr)`
  let total = 0;
  while (sortedLen < arr.length) {
    
    let min = arr[sortedLen];
    for (let i = sortedLen; i < arr.length; i++) {
      
      if (arr[i]) {
        
        arr[i] -= lastMin;
        if (arr[i]) min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);
        
      } else {
        
        arr[i] = arr[sortedLen];
        arr[sortedLen] = total;
        sortedLen++;
        
      }
      
    }
    
    total += lastMin;
    lastMin = min;
    
  }
  return arr;
  
};

let examples = [
  [ 3, 2, 5, 4, 8, 5, 7, 1 ],
  [ 3000, 2000, 5000, 4000, 8000, 5000, 7000, 1000 ],
  [ 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.1 ],
  [ 26573726573, 678687, 3490, 465684586 ]
];
for (let example of examples) {
  console.log(`Unsorted: ${example.join(', ')}`);
  console.log(`Sorted:   ${subtractSort(example).join(', ')}`);
  console.log('');
}
```

Note this sort only works with positive numbers. To work with negative numbers we would need to find the most negative item, subtract this negative value from every item in the array, sort the array, and finally add the most negative value back to every item - overall this doesn't increase time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of a sort algorithm that has linear time complexity (if `k` is taken as constant), `O(1)` auxiliary space complexity, and is stable too. This is an implementation I wrote of the "binary radix sort" that user ciamej told about in his answer. I could not find any implementation of this algorithm on the internet which satisfied all 3 properties which is why I felt it would be a good idea to add it over here. You can try it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/rku8pKQXv).

```
// Binary Radix Sort
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int print_arr(int arr[], int n)
{
  int z;
  for(z=0 ; z<n ; z++)
  {
    printf("%d ", arr[z]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
int getMax(int arr[], int n) 
{ 
  int mx = arr[0]; 
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
      if (arr[i] > mx) 
          mx = arr[i]; 
  return mx; 
} 
void BinaryRadixSort(int arr[], int arr_size)
{
  int biggest_int_len = log2(getMax(arr, arr_size))+1;
  int i;
  int digit;
  for(i=1 ; i<=biggest_int_len ; i++)
  {
    digit=i;
    int j;
    int bit;
    int pos=0;
    int min=-1;
    int min2=-1;
    int min_val;
    for(j=0 ; j<arr_size ; j++)
    {
      int len=(int) (log2(arr[j])+1);
      if(i>len)
      {
        bit=0;
      }
      else
      {
        bit=(arr[j] & (1 << (digit - 1)));
      }
      if(bit==0)
      {
        min_val=arr[j];
        min=j;
        min2=j;
        break;
      }
    }
    while(min!=-1)
    {
      while(min>pos)
      {
        arr[min]=arr[min-1];
        min--;
      }
      arr[pos]=min_val;
      pos++;
      int k;
      min=-1;
      for(k=min2+1 ; k<arr_size ; k++)
      {
        int len=(int) (log2(arr[k])+1);
        if(i>len)
        {
          bit=0;
        }
        else
        {
          bit= arr[k] & (1 << (digit-1));
        }
        if(bit==0)
        {
          min_val=arr[k];
          min=k;
          min2=k;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
int main()
{
  int arr[16]={10,43,73,14,64,2,6,1,5,3,6,3,5,8,4,5};
  int size=16;
  BinaryRadixSort(arr, size);
  printf("\n--------------------------\n");
  print_arr(arr, size);
  return 0;
}
```

The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(log2(k).n)`, where `k` is the biggest number in the list and `n` is the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a sort algorithm that has linear time complexity and O(1) auxiliary space complexity. I'll call it subtract-sort. Here is the code in C (runnable [here](https://onlinegdb.com/r1M9lP-QD)).

```
// Subtract Sort
#include<stdio.h>
int print_arr(int arr[], int n)
{
  int z;
  for(z=0 ; z<n ; z++)
  {
    printf("%d ", arr[z]);
  }
}
void subtract_sort(int arr[], int arr_size)
{
  int j=0;
  int val=1;
  int all_zero=0;
  while(!all_zero)
  {
    int m;
    all_zero=1;
    int i;
    for(i=j ; i<arr_size ; i++)
    {
      arr[i]--;
      if(arr[i]==0)
      {
        arr[i]=arr[j];
        arr[j]=val;
        j++;
      }
      all_zero=0;
    }
    val++;
  }
}
int main()
{
  int arr[12]={2,10,3,7,9,8,54,3,9,38,8};
  int size=11;
  subtract_sort(arr, size);
  printf("\n--------------------------\n");
  print_arr(arr, size);
  return 0;
}
```

The algorithm has a worst-case time complexity of `O(kn)`, where `k` is the biggest element of the array. This algorithm is efficient for large arrays containing small values (outperforming quicksort), but very inefficient for small arrays containing large values. The time complexity is also exactly equal to `sum(arr)` which is the sum of all the elements in the array.

To all those who say that this algorithm does not have linear time, find me an array that exceeds my calculated worst-case time complexity of `O(kn)`. If such a counterexample is found, I will happily agree with you.

Maybe [this example](https://onlinegdb.com/rJEfit-mD) of a worst-case scenario would help in understanding the time complexity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220388/discussion-on-answer-by-mathphile-is-there-a-sorting-algorithm-with-linear-time).